# "Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined" when using grid.setFilter(...)

Tags: javascript, json, string, dojo

I want to set my filter plugin for my enhanced grid programmatically. Thats my approach:

```
//concat query string
console.log(queryString);
grid.setFilter(queryString, 'logicany');
```

I get the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined FilterDefDialog.js.uncompressed.js:949
```

and the console log for query string looks like

```
[{type:'string',column:1,condition:'contains',value:'test'},{type:'string',column:1,condition:'contains',value:'13'}]
```

But when I set a hardcoded query string like this:

```
grid.setFilter([{type:'string',column:1,condition:'contains',value:'test'},{type:'string',column:1,condition:'contains',value:'13'}], 'logicany');
```

it works. Whats wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try converting the String into a JSON Object and passing that.
If you are using jQuery then use parseJSON.

```
var objQueryString = $.parseJSON(queryString);

grid.setFilter(objQueryString , 'logicany');
```